# How to reproduce `JacobianMatrix` function

Tags: packages, vector-calculus, compatibility

I want to use the `JacobianMatrix` function in package `VectorAnalysis`, but I get the following warning message after running the following code.

```
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
JacobianMatrix[{Rr, Ttheta, Zz}, Cylindrical]
General::obspkg: VectorAnalysis` is now obsolete. The legacy version being loaded may conflict with current functionality. See the Compatibility Guide for updating information.
```

But I didn't find the same function in the built-in functions. What should I do to reproduce this function.

I want to reproduce the function in various common coordinate systems.

Comment: Search `JacobianMatrix` in the document and the solution is in  _VectorAnalysis\`  Compatibility Information_. (The first link in _v9_ and the second link in _v12.1_. )

Comment: While this can be done with built-in tools (see kglr's answer), why don't you just use `D[{r Cos[\[Theta]], r Sin[\[Theta]], z}, {{r, \[Theta], z}, 1}]`? It is unambiguous, concise, and universally applicable (i.e., not limited to a few hard-coded transformations).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146849/1871